# Open/Show/Pop up app from background on Flutter

Tags: popup, flutter, show

is there an actual way to show/pop up the app from the background due to a background event, like detecting a beacon?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey did you get any solution for this one

Comment: Hey Savad, not for that time ago. I don't think this is possible nowadays :(

Comment: So  is there any solution for this . I need my app to open or at-least open some screen in when i get some notification from backend . Something like WhatsApp . When i get WhatsApp call it open up one screen

Comment: @Savad I think that features like this are only available in apps that are specifically made for this (VoIP).